# Different text size on the same images

Tags: c#, size, drawstring

I have 2 same images.
When I try to add rectangle and text (using graphics) to this images, the rectangle is the same BUT the text on image is different size..

the code is:

```
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 5), new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 100));
g.DrawString("GONgon", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 20, 20);
```

originals of images here:

[first](http://snoopme.ru/f1.jpg)

[second](http://snoopme.ru/f2.jpg)

Comment: Check to see if they really have the same `DPI` setting!!

Comment: The 1st image has an odd-ball 72 dpi resolution, the 2nd is 96 dpi.  Be specific about the unit of measurement for the Font.  Right now it is *points* and that's a dpi dependent unit.  Fixing the image wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `GraphicsUnit = Pixel` in the `System.Drawing.Font()`. Like `System.Drawing.Font(fontName,fontSize,fontStyle,GraphicsUnit.Pixel)`.